# SQL: Remove rows with a duplicate field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have duplicate entries due to a programming error.

Table Example:

```
id | group | userNum | username | name
---------------------------------------
1  | AA11  |   D-01  |   user1  | Donald
2  | AA11  |   D-02  |   user2  | Cruz
3  | AA11  |   D-03  |   user3  | Rubio
4  | AA11  |   D-01  |   user1  | Donald    <------DUPLICATE
5  | AA11  |   D-04  |   user4  | Cruz
6  | AA22  |   D-03  |   user2  | Rubio
7  | AA22  |   D-02  |   user1  | Donald
```

userNum, username must be unique to each group, but a group can have userNum, username, name which are found in other groups.

Comment: Which database are you using?  There are several different ways to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Comment: Once you resolve this issue, alter your table to include the constraint for the primary key which includes userNum and username. So that this kind of errors will not appear in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard SQL approach is to use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause.  For instance:

```
delete from example
    where id not in (select min(id)
                     from example e2
                     group by group, userNum, username, name
                    );
```

This doesn't work in MySQL.  You can do something similar using `left join`:

```
delete e
    from example e left join
         (select min(id) as minid
          from example e2
          group by group, userNum, username, name
         ) ee
         on e.id = ee.minid
    where ee.minid is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `group by userNum, username, group` at the end of your query..